If two infinite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic, does an inner product isomorphism exist between them?
The following proposition is true:
If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$, the following is equivalent.
$\quad$ (1) $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic as inner product space.
$\quad$ (2) $\dim V = \dim W$.
What I'm curious about is whether this holds true even when V and W have infinite dimension.
In my intuition, it seems (1) $\to$ (2) is true and (2) $\to$ (1) is false, but I can't prove it or find a counterexample.
Thanks!

What is $F$? Anyway your allegdedly true proposition sounds weird since you are not assuming a priori $V,W$ equipped with some inner product.

If you are asking if there exist inner products on $V$ and $W$ and an inner product preserving linear bijection between them, the answer is yes. If you are asking if this  holds for specified inner products the answer is no.

I considered a situation where the inner product of $V$ and $W$ was given. Thanks for the reply! $F$ indicate base field, especially in the textbooks I read, real or complex.

This works in finite dimension because all inner products are equivalent, i.e. for any fixed vector space there is a linear automorphism which takes one inner product to another. In infinite dimension, all inner products are not equivalent.

If by $\dim$ you meant linear dimension (i.e., cardinality of a Hamel basis), then your intuition is correct. $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ simply follows by noting every isomorphism as inner product spaces is also a linear isomorphism, whence preserves the dimension. For $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$, there are plenty of counterexamples - $c_{00}(\mathfrak{c})$, the space of finitely supported sequences on $\mathfrak{c}$, the cardinality of the continuum, equipped with the standard inner product, has the same dimension (namely, $\mathfrak{c}$) as $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, but the latter is complete while the former is not, so they are not isomorphic as inner product spaces. Even restricting to complete inner product spaces (i.e., Hilbert spaces), the answer is still no, as $\ell^2(\mathfrak{c})$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ both have dimension $\mathfrak{c}$, but the latter is separable while the former is not, so they are not isomorphic as inner product spaces.

I’m assuming here that $V$ and $W$ are already equipped with pre-fixed inner products.

Thank you for the great answer!

@FromLaTeXBeginer No problems! If you find the answer satisfactory you can accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left.
